# Reset Cloudflare's Rocket Loader

Tags: cloudflare

I want to reset CloudFlare's Rocket Loader, so that it acquires the latest JS from third party scripts that have been updated.

Pressing Purge Cache does not seem to affect the Rocket Loader JS.
Toggling Rocket Loader's modes does not reset the cached version used in the Automatic mode.

How do you force Rocket Loader to serve the latest versions third party scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Rocket Loader just uses the scripts currently on your site. It does not maintain any kind of cache of scripts.

If you are seeing some type of issue I'd suggest opening a support ticket with CloudFlare directly so our support team can review your account settings.

p.s. I work at CloudFlare, and spoke with the developer that maintains Rocket Loader.

Comment: I am testing the behavior of the third party script when users have not embedded our third party script with the data-cfasync='false'. As I understand it, Rocket Loader minifies the script and combines it with other external scripts referenced on the page into a single file do minimize http hits and download time. Unfortunately, it also seems to ignore the caching rules on that script. I was trying to update the third party script (that I also to control) but the page continued to serve the old script, until I turned Rocket Loader off. I would like to force RL to serve the updated script.

Answer (score 0):

"I was trying to update the third party script (that I also to control) but the page continued to serve the old script, until I turned Rocket Loader off. I would like to force RL to serve the updated script"

This actually seems more like an issue with caching of that script than Rocket Loader. Are you using any other caching plugins or services on the site? Our purge cache option should work on the file (purge cache or single file purge), but you could also be seeing caching related to another service you may be running on the site.

Comment: I am working on a third party script (domain1), that gets served on sites using CloudFlare. They have embedded our code without the data-cfasync='false' attribute. I wanted to emulate that behaviour locally, so I have a site (domain2) which just has CloudFlare, no other services, and is serving our third party script. If I turn off Rocket Loader the script from (domain1) is kept up to date and obeys caching rules, with Rocket Launcher off (on domain2), it does not update according to the caching rules and most often serves an out of date version of the script (from domain1).

Comment: Hi,

Rocket Loader doesn't have anything to do with caching (it isn't a caching feature). The issue sounds more like you changed the file & didn't purge the cache (single file or full purge).